# Create JSON file with urls of all pages with specific keywords in Scrapy

Tags: python, json, file, scrapy

I am parsing multiple URLs/pages in scrapy. On each page, it searches for specific keywords and if found, append the URL in Attribute_Dictionary.

As, each URL being parsed, Attribute_Dictionary gets updated every time. Now I want to write a json file of Attribute_Dictionary only ONCE when I am done with parsing of All URLs.

Currently I have written code to dump content in to JSON but it creates JSON file again and again (in a single run) and override the last created json file.
Desired output is a json file with all urls in Attribure_Dictionary.

Please help. Should I create a global variable to handle all pages that are parsed? If yes then how to do it?

```
def parse(self, response):
    global parsed_urls
    global domain_urls
    global tld
    global sliced_url
    items = []
    global item



    if ('html' not in response.headers['Content-Type']):
        return

    sel = Selector(response)


    for h3 in sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract():
         #print h3 + "***********" + ' <' + response.url + '>'
         sliced_url = response.url.split('/')[2]


    for url in sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract():

        if (url.startswith('/')):

            url = 'http://' + sliced_url + url



        if (url in parsed_urls or len(url) > 250):
            continue

        parsed_urls.append(url)

        if tld in url:
            domain_urls.append(url)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

        #print parsed_urls
        for keyword in Keyword_Dictionary:

            if (url.startswith('http') and (tld in url)):
                if (self.Search_keyword_in_url(keyword, response)):
                    if keyword not in Url_Dictionary:
                        Url_Dictionary[keyword] = []
                    Url_Dictionary[keyword].append(url)
                    #print keyword + " " + "Detected"



        for keyword in Url_Dictionary:

            Attribute_Key = []
            Attribute_Key = Keyword_Dictionary.get(keyword)
            Attribute_Key_Value = Url_Dictionary.get(keyword)
            for key in Attribute_Key:
                if key not in Attribute_Dictionary:
                    Attribute_Dictionary[key] = []
                    print key
                    print "\n"
                    for value in Attribute_Key_Value:
                        if value not in Attribute_Dictionary.get(key):
                            Attribute_Dictionary[key].append(value)
                            print key + " " + "Just Appended"
                            item = Website()
                            Modified_Key = key.replace(" ","_")
                            item[Modified_Key] = response.url
                            print item[Modified_Key]

        print Attribute_Dictionary
        # Json Code
        fileptr = open('keywords_spider.json','a')
        json.dump(Attribute_Dictionary, fileptr, indent=4)
        print "Created keywords_spiders.json.."
        fileptr.close()




def Search_keyword_in_url(self, keyword, response):

    sel = Selector(response)

    text_list = sel.xpath('//div/p/text()').extract()
    for text in text_list:
        if text.find(keyword) > -1:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Can you provide the url(s) you are trying to process?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is too complicated for what you are trying to accomplish. I would use`Item` to help simplify things. Read the docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html). Also, trying to write files yourself isn't the best way to do things. Using `Items` lets Scrapy handle outputs for you. You can easily change the output format, or extend functionality using an[`Item Pipeline`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

I'll leave a solution in case you decide to use them. In your project, create a file *items.py* in the same level as the *spiders* directory.

```
#items.py

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class myFunkyUrlItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    keyword = Field()
```

Now in your scraper, use the existing logic to find elements. And when you find them, create a`myFunkyUrlItem`

```
**#The Crawler!**
#import our custom item
from myProjectName.items import myFunkyUrlItem

def parse(self,response):
######Your existing scraper####
...
...
...

#When found
url_item = myFunkyUrlItem()    
url_item['url'] = response.url
url_item['keyword'] = the_keyword_found #Change this

#Give item to scrapy to process 
return url_item
```

Now, finally when running the crawler, tell Scrapy to dump all items found as json.

```
scrapy crawl myFunkySpider -o items.json
```

Now,

```
import json

my_items = json.load(open('items.json'))

print my_items[0]['url']
print my_items[0]['keyword']
```

I hope this helps. I'm still not very sure I understood your question. If this was not what you were looking for, comment!

Comment: This is 'the solution' as much I understand the question. There is a need to get a global state of all crawling process and items clearly solves it